# Список словарей cо значениями списков

Tags: python, список, словарь

Дан список словарей:

```
a = [
  {"name": "Tom", "bag": ["black", "pink"]},
  {"name": "Mark", "bag": ["red", "green"]},
  {"name": "Pam", "bag": ["no"]}
]
```

Как можно вывести словарь в котором значение ключа:

```
"bag": ["no"]
```

Пытался методом next:

```
def b():
    return next(element for element in a if element["bag"] == ["no"])
```

Большое спасибо за любые советы

Comment: <offtopic>а почему вы всегда удаляете свои вопросы после того как получили ответ(ы)?</offtopic>

Comment: `return [ {d:element[d]} for element in a  for d in element  if element[d]==['no'] ]`

Answer (score 1):

Так например

```
a = [
  {"name": "Tom", "bag": ["black", "pink"]},
  {"name": "Mark", "bag": ["red", "green"]},
  {"name": "Pam", "bag": ["no"]}
]

for dic in a:
    for key, value in dic.items():
        if key == "bag" and value == ["no"]:
            print(dic)
            break
```

вывод:

```
{'name': 'Pam', 'bag': ['no']}
```

Answer (score 1):

Пример реализации:

```py
a = [
  {"name": "Tom", "bag": ["black", "pink"]},
  {"name": "Mark", "bag": ["red", "green"]},
  {"name": "Pam", "bag": ["no"]}
]

result = next((dictionary for dictionary in a if dictionary["bag"] == ["no"]))
print(result) # {'name': 'Pam', 'bag': ['no']}
```

`(dictionary for dictionary in a if dictionary["bag"] == ["no"])` - создает ленивый iterator, который ищет в `a` элемент удволетворяющий условию `dictionary["bag"] == ["no"]`

Метод `next` возвращает первый элемент iterator'a

Comment: как по мне, лучше без некст,

Answer (score 1):

Алексей Яковлев дал правильный ответ. На мой взгляд моя реализация более соответствует вопросу, т.к. выводит *все* такие словари списком, а не *первый*.

К тому же, в случае с неудавшимся поиском в варианте Алексея прилетит "исключение" и программа аварийно завершится.
Поэтому вот - та же мысль, но чуток аккуратнее:

```
a = [
  {"name": "Tom", "bag": ["black", "pink"]},
  {"name": "Mark", "bag": ["red", "green"]},
  {"name": "Pam", "bag": ["no"]}
]

try:
    result = [ dictionary for dictionary in a if dictionary["bag"] == ["no"] ]
except:
    result =[]

print(result) # [{'name': 'Pam', 'bag': ['no']}]
```

тогда вы в любом случае получаете список всех результатов поиска.
Если искомого нет - пустой список, если искомые словари есть - список таких словарей!